# Ubunutu installation

Tags: system-installation, usb, hard-drive, bios

I've installed Ubuntu from USB flash drive. All fine but now - continues to boot from USB. How do I revert to startup from HDD. Tried BIOS - only option listed is USB.

Comment: I'm assume you installed from USB to HDD (or SSD)? Did you choose to use whole disk installation or something else? Did you check that if doing a full disk install that the boot installer would be on the HDD? See the official install guide here [https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop). Step 4 shows a drop-down box of where ubuntu will be installed. This would also be where the boot loader is installed. Don't forget to take out the USB once prompted at the end of installation (just prior to rebooting)

Comment: The easiest, simplest solution is to unplug the USB device and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

In your BIOS two options control that. 1st - order of booting 2nd - hard drives devices. You have to find the 2nd option and change there.

Or as people said remove USB and reboot.